# Why am I getting undefined in output when typing object.key but getting correct output typing object[key]. What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, object

[image: difference between "." & "[]"]

difference between "." & "[]"

Comment: Please, copy and paste your code rather than using screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

You have no "key" attribute to your object. Hence the undefined. `object.key` would be defined only if your object contained a 'key' field. `object.afaque` for example is 95. But it needs to be literal afaque. You cannot access a field with `.` operator from a variable containing field name. You can do that with '[]' operator tho.

What you want to do is probably

```js
for(let key in object){
   console.log("Marks of", key, "are", object[key]);
}
```

Difference between both is that one precisely.

in `A[B]`, B is an expression that is evaluated to a key (a string in your case), and A[B] is the value associated to that key in A. If you wanted to use `A[B]` notation with a static field name, you would need to enclose that field name into double quotes. Because it is a string value.
`object["lafaque"]` for example.

in `A.B`, B is an attribute name. It is part of javascript syntax. Like a variable name for example. Like in the expression `key=12;`. Typing that, you expect the variable `key` to be set to 12. Not the variable `afaque` because value of key would be "afaque". `key` in both `key=12` or `object.key` are not strings. It is the "key" identifier, parsed and interpreted by the language as a variable name in the 1st case, or a field name in the 2nd.

in `object["lafaque"]`, "lafaque" is a string. As in `object["la"+"faque"]` or `object[key]` or `object[convolutedWay("to", compute, "a string")]`